# Why Spring Security authentication causes CORS error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors

I have a backend server made in Java with Spring Boot, Security and Web and a client made with Angular.

Currently I am trying to make a simple request under `localhost:8080/resource`.

The controller for this address is shown bellow:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String, Object> home() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");

        return model;
    }
}
```

And the Angular client (the part that performs the request) is this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public title = "Security Client";
    public greeting = {};

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.get("http://localhost:8080/resource").subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
    }
}
```

The problem by using just what was shown is that I get a CORS error.

Whether removing Spring Security from my `pom.xml` or adding this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resource").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Solves the problem.

What I wanna know is why I am getting an CORS error instead of a 401 Unauthorized when accessing an address that demands user authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the spring boot documentation:

> For security reasons, browsers prohibit AJAX calls to resources
>   outside the current origin. For example, you could have your bank
>   account in one tab and evil.com in another. Scripts from evil.com
>   should not be able to make AJAX requests to your bank API with your
>   credentials — for example withdrawing money from your account!
>
> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a W3C specification
>   implemented by most browsers that lets you specify what kind of
>   cross-domain requests are authorized, rather than using less secure
>   and less powerful workarounds based on IFRAME or JSONP.

You're getting this error because you need to add a filter in your security configuration. In your configure, add:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resource").permitAll();
}
```

In the same file, you should add:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", 
    "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", 
    "x-auth-token"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

    return source;
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: But why without it I get CORS error instead of a 401?

Comment: I assume it happens because the cors filter is processed before the authentication one.

Comment: CORS validation occurs before making the POST, GET... requests through an OPTIONS request (which is called by the way a pre-flight request). To understand better the request flow you can check [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png)

Answer (score 3):

> What I wanna know is **why I am getting an CORS error** instead of a 401
>   Unauthorized when accessing an address that demands user
>   authentication.

You get this error because before your actual request (POST, GET...), the browser performs a pre-flight request (**OPTIONS**) to validate if in fact the called server is able to handle CORS requests.

During this request, the `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Header` are validated and some other info are added to the header.

You receive the CORS error then because **your actual request is not even done** if CORS validation **failed** on the OPTIONS request.

You can check a flowchart of how CORS validation works [in here](https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png)

An interesting point is that you will only get a HTTP error status like 401 during the pre-flight request when the server is not authorized to answer the OPTIONS request.